# A widget like a TabBar, which can be Expanded or Scroll depending on the width of the children

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, widget, tabbar

Does anyone know how to implement a widget in the likeness of a TabBar, so that the tabs divide the entire space by width, if the sum of the width of all tabs is less than the width of the screen. If the sum of the width of all tabs is greater than the width of the screen, then leave their size as it is and make them scroll horizontally?

Example when the sum of the width of all tabs is **less** than the width of the screen:
[image]

Example when the sum of the width of all tabs is **greater** than the width of the screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by: setting `isScrollable` to true and `labelPadding` to `EdgeInsets.zero` and `indicatorSize` to `TabBarIndicatorSize.label` .
Now you can achieve that thing with these properties of Tabbar.